# Отправка 2 форм 1 запросом

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

В общем - у меня на странице есть 2 формы. Они в разных местах страницы и даже в разных файлах темы.

Мне нужно при сабмите одной формы, чтобы данные из второй тоже уходили на тот же обработчик и при этом - в одном POST запросе.

Не нагуглил как такое сделать.

Comment: Страшно представить, что вы пытаетесь сделать ))) Зачем такое извращение? )) А если серьёзно, конечно же вы не сможете отправить одновременно данные с двух форм, но вы можете собрать данные со всех форм в одну форму и отправлять только её. Например, у вас по 5 полей в каждой форме, вы создаёте  одну невидимую форму с `input type="hidden"` и при заполнении полей, значение каждой записываете в нужный невидимый инпут. При нажатии на отправку любых из двух форм, посредством `js` отправляете эту невидимую форму, надеюсь логика понятна..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема уже где-то была:

Вариант первый:

Можно попробовать создать третью скрытую форму, которая будет сериализовать поля из обоих.

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
.........
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post">
.........
</form>
```

На jQuery:

```
var str1 = $("form1").serialize();
var str2 = $("form2").serialize();
$.post(url, str1 + "&" + str2);
```

Вариант второй:

Через ajax (у каждой формы свой id):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var formID = $(this).attr('id'); // Получение ID формы
            var formNm = $('#' + formID);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mail.php', // Обработчик формы отправки
                data: formNm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    // Вывод текста результата отправки в текущей форме
                    $(formNm).html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

*Если запустить `$('form').serialize()` на странице с несколькими формами, она будет правильно сериализовать все формы в одну строку, ну, а для включения только определенных форм, можно указать конкретно `$('#form1, #form2').serialize()`.

Comment: А тег `<form>` не должен быть одни на странице?

Comment: @doox911 Добавил в ответ относящееся.